# linker command failed while trying to compile .c file with g++

Tags: c

Just posted a simple c code and gotten this error message. can anyone explain where the problem could be?

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
mac@MACs-MacBook-Pro-2 C % cd "/Users/mac/C/" && g++ tes.c++ -o tes && "/Users/mac/C/"tes
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
```

Comment: you have to compile with `gcc` and not `g++`

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: "Undefined symbol main" usually means you're missing the critical `main()` function.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I'm actually new in programming.. here is the code, it just a basic 'hello world' algorithm 
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}

Comment: @kaylum please take a look

Answer (score 2):

you have to compile with gcc and not g++, g++ is to compile .cpp or .cc files

```
gcc tes.c++ -o tes
```

Comment: Last login: Fri Mar  5 02:23:16 on ttys002
mac@MACs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % gcc
clang: error: no input files
mac@MACs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ %      ... Here is the message from my terminal, I thought gcc compiler was installed successfully too. I  initially installed g++ and I did the same for gcc , I don't know where the problem is , please help

Comment: `cd Users/mac/C/ && gcc tes.c -o tes && ./Users/mac/C/tes`

Comment: or, if your file is a c++ file: `cd Users/mac/C/ && g++ tes.cpp -o tes && ./Users/mac/C/tes` NB: c++ files have `.cpp` extension file name and not `.c++`